# JavaScript if the first datetime is greater than the second datetime

Tags: javascript

I have looked at a number of questions concerning how this is done but none of them work with my code. I am trying to find out if the "nowdate" is less than "startdate". The code below is what I have so far:

INPUT :

Start date: 01-03-2019 00:00

End date:   31-03-2019 23:59

My code;

```
var nowdate;
var d = new Date();
nowdate = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + d.getFullYear()  + " " + ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

This produces : Now date:   17-02-2019 16:43

```
if(nowdate < startdate){
  console.log("Start date is greater than now date");
} else {
  console.log("Start date is NOT greater than now date")
}
```

This does not produce the result I am expecting. Why is that?

Comment: Change `nowdate` to format `'02-17-2019 17:05'` and use the `Date` object methods. Where is "startdate" used in the code?

Comment: Why are you manually creating a `Date` string? Please learn more about JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Date.prototype.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) when you want to compare two dates

```js
let startDate = (new Date('01-03-2019 00:00')).getTime()
let nowDate = (new Date()).getTime();
if(nowDate < startDate){
    console.log("Start date is greater than now date");
}
else{
    console.log("Start date is NOT greater than now date")
}
```